# Prompt for yes or no - without repeating on new line if wrong input

Tags: powershell

I have this simple bit of code in a PS script where I want to get a simple yes or no answer. Then I'm just doing an if ($answer -eq "y") {install roles} and if ($answer -eq "n") {don't install roles}

```
if ($roles -eq "1") {
do {
$answer = read-host -prompt "Found missing roles. Install them now? (y/n)"
until ($answer -eq "y" or $answer -eq "n")
   }
}
```

The problem is that when user inputs something other than y or n it reprompts on new line. So essentially they could keep pressing ENTER and it'll just fill the PS window with it and the menu that was visible will scroll off the screen. So I don't want to clear the screen either.

How can I avoid the new line and make the code as simple and easy to understand as possible? If there's an easier or better way to accomplish this without do..until then that's fine as long as it's clean & simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this option...

```
If ($Roles -eq '1') {
    $Cursor = [System.Console]::CursorTop
    Do {
        [System.Console]::CursorTop = $Cursor
        Clear-Host
        $Answer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Found missing roles. Install them now? (y/n)'
    }
    Until ($Answer -eq 'y' -or $Answer -eq 'n')
}
```

**Edit**: I ended up writing a blog about this question and answer. You can read it here: https://powershell.org/2020/02/forum-problem-to-posted-solution-and-article-post/

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was going to ask next (if we can just cursor up). I didn't want to clear the screen so after removing the clear-host command everything's working great.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues coding in PowerShell, and the problem I've run into is the different hosts (Normal PowerShell.EXE vs. PowerShell_ISE.EXE) and how they handle the UI differently.  As an example, you can read a key from the keyboard using $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey(), but only in PowerShell.EXE host, not in ISE.  Without clearing the screen and re-drawing the question, you really don't have a lot of viable options that work in all situations.

The most simple, most elegant way of handling situations like this, in my opinion, is to treat this more like a social engineering problem and less like a programming problem.  What I mean is, rephrase your question so that the risky option is tested and everything else is the safe option.  In your case, if installing the additional roles should only be done if absolutely necessary, rewrite your question like:

```
if ($roles -eq "1") {
    $answer = read-host -prompt "Found missing roles. Press 'Y' to install them"
}
```

Then, if $answer -eq 'Y', do your install, otherwise, regardless of what else they type, do not install.

If, however, installing the roles where unnecessary isn't so bad, you might rewrite the question like:

```
if ($roles -eq "1") {
    $answer = read-host -prompt "Ready to install missing roles. Press 'N' to skip the installation."
}
```

In this case, you would install UNLESS the user types 'N'.

Sometimes, as programmers, we try to solve human problems with more coding, when actually the human solution is much more simple.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks but the accepted answer does what I wanted. I didn't want the question to keep repeating on a new line if they kept pressing the wrong key but rather repeat it on the same line.

Comment: My suggested changes will not result in repetition at all, since the answer is accepted regardless of what they type.  My suggestion changes the question from a "Y/N" type question to a "Y/everythingelse" type.  Glad you were able to find an answer to do what you were trying to do although for those who come later, the accepted answer does NOT work in PowerShell ISE, only in the standard PowerShell Host.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. What it does is take the coordinates of the cursor before the input and then moves it back after the input is given. It will work no matter where you are in your script and won't affect any previous lines.

```
if ($roles -eq "1") {
    Write-Host "Found missing roles. Install them now? (y/n): " -NoNewline
    do {
    #get current cursor positions before the Read-Host
    $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.X
    $y = $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.Y

    $answer = Read-Host
    #set the cursor coordinates back to before the Read-Host
    $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates $x,$y
    }
    until ($answer -eq "y" -or $answer -eq "n")
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Yes this works too although it has the exact same effect as tommymaynard's answer only slightly more code.

Comment: agreed! after looking at tommymaynard's, his is certainly the best solution.